# Full Motion Video over Wireless Projection

Tags: wifi, display

I'm looking for a solution to get graphics from a tablet to a projector wirelessly.  The idea is to have the professor connect to the the solution and then connect to a network share, load their powerpoint/video/content and then output their screen to the projector while being able to walk around the room during class.

We have been using a solution called 'AirProjector' which went out of business several years back.  Major downfall of of the AirProjector was video is very choppy.  The more screen the device had to update the slower and poorer the display was to the point where animation was taboo.

Any suggestions on a solution to the above?  Even if we dont' gain full motion video maintaning the level of service would be nice.  This change is required as we are moving from an open wireless network to requireing WPA2 Personal(we don't have the time to dedicate to getting WPA2 Enterprise up right now) and the device only supports WEP at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using wireless VGA? 
http://www.iogear.com/product/GUW2015VKIT/

Comment: That particular item didn't look like it supported the audio but tech support reccomended a similar item on their site so I'll check it out and see if fits our needs.